# I need to pass string from one function to other in c. How do I make this work?

Tags: c

```
void getquestionasked(char quest[]);

int main()
{
    char question[150];
    getquestionasked(question);
    printf("%s", question);
    return 0;
}


void getquestionasked(char quest[])
{
    quest = "In what unit is electric power measured?";
}
```

Comment: Use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to copy strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
#include <string.h>

//…

strcpy( quest, "In what unit is electric power measured?" );
```